# Unions preserve left-infinite sets, those of the form $(a,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

As part of some extra credit my professor gave me, I am given this problem:

> Call a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ left-inﬁnite if either $A =\mathbb R$ or $A=(a,\infty)$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$.
>
> (a) Give an example of a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ that is left-inﬁnite and an example of a subset that is not left-inﬁnite.
>
> (b) Prove that if A and B are left-inﬁnite, then so is $A\cup B$.
>
> (c) Prove that if $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of left-inﬁnite sets, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is left-inﬁnite.

For (a), am I correct in saying an answer such as $A=\{1, 5, 2\}$ and $B=\{\sqrt{-1},\infty\}$?

For (b), I know that we define $A$ and $B$ to be sets of real numbers, so is it possible for me to say that since the elements of both sets are left-infinite, any numbers in the set of the intersection of $A$ and $B$ are left-infinite, and as such the set of the intersection is left-infinite?

I have no idea what to do for (c).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing $(a,\infty)$ with $\{a,\infty\}$. The latter is the set having $a$ and $\infty$ as elements, the former is
$$
(a,\infty)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a<x\}
$$
In particular, every left-infinite set (I'd call them *right-infinite*, though) is unbounded and has infinitely many elements.

Just to make a pictorial view of $(a,\infty)$, you're in a situation like
$$
-\;-\;-\;-\;-\overset{a}{\circ}\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\qquad\qquad\qquad}
$$
and the set $(a,\infty)$ is represented by the continuous half line.

The examples requested for (a) are easy to find. In (b) you probably have to show that if $A$ and $B$ are left-infinite then so is their *intersection* $A\cap B$, as the question about the union is a special case of question (c).

For both, use the pictorial representation to make a guess (hint: supremum and infimum are involved) about what the intersection or union should be.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), by your definition, $A=\{1,5,2\}$ is not left infinite. $B=\{\sqrt{-1}, \infty\}$, however, is also not a left infinite subset of $\mathbb R$, simply because it is **not a subset of** $\mathbb R$ at all!

For (b): No, it is not possible to say it that way. Elements of a set are not left infinite.The ses themselves are. What you need to do is (rigorously, not by hand waving!) take any two left infinite sets $A$ and $B$ and *show* that $A\cup B$ is left infinite. As a hint: If $A$ is left infinite, by definition, what does it look like? And what does $B$ look like? Now, what does $C$ look like then?

For (c): The hint from (b) also applies here. What does $A_i$ look like?